# SQL Server where using multiple data types

Tags: c#, sql-server

I couldn't come up with a better title.

I have a list of values like:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>() {"1", "AND", "2", "NOT", "3"}
```

And a database table which contains the ids specified in the list above.
My problem is that I need to retrieve the data based on the ids, including the values which are not found in the table ( the operators `AND` and `NOT` for the list above). 
For example, using the list above, after reading the db values for `1`,`2` and `3` a new list will be created like:

```
List<string> values = {"Value1", "AND", "Value2", "NOT", "Value3"}
```

The operators, `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, `)` and `(` are just simple strings which are not found in `MyTable`.

Until now I was splitting the ids and for each value I do a trip to the db and get the value. The problem with this is that it takes a lot of time even for 2k lists. A list has around 10 values each.

What I was thinking about is to use the `where in` clause which will hopefully reduce the trips to the database. Unfortunately, I don't know how to handle the operators from the first list. (The operators are not saved in `MyTable` ).

I've tried using multiple where conditions but I cannot convert the operators (which are strings) to `int` (type of the Id column).

Queries I've tried:

```
SELECT Title
  FROM MyTable where Id =1 or Id = cast('AND' as int)
```

And

```
SELECT Title
  FROM MyTable where Id in (1,2,'AND')
```

Both of them fail (rightfully) because sql cannot convert `AND` to data type `int`.

What I want is to use the `where` clause (or any other) for the first list and where there is no result found in the db return the value used in the query. 
For example, for the query:

```
 SELECT Title
      FROM MyTable where Id in (1,2,'AND')
```

I'd like to receive from the db `Value1`, `Value2`, `AND`. I know that the order is not guaranteed when executing the query.

How could I solve this problem efficiently? I'm using `c#` with `sql server 2012` without any orm

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. In your list is `"AND"` an ID? Or is it intended to be a Boolean operator?

Comment: @Ben edited the question, `AND` is just a string used later in the application. These operators are not saved in the database at all.

Comment: If these "operators" are not saved to the database then why do your queries contain them?

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you are trying to do. You need to do that if you want helpful suggestions.

Comment: what data type is `Id`? if it is `[n][var]char({max|len})`, then: just don't cast the `"1"` and `"2"` etc to integers - treat them as strings throughout; ideally, parameterized - so `Id in ('1','2','AND') ` or `Id in (@p0,@p1,@p2)`. If `Id` is an `int` - don't pass down non-integer values, since it can't possibly be a match. So: exclude the `"AND"` much earlier

Comment: @Ben, i did, check the last paragraph.

Comment: @MarcGravell I need the result to be in the same order as in the first list. `Id` is of type `Int`

Comment: If by "Preserve the list order", you mean that you want the select result to be in the same order as the where clause, you need to add some kind of ORDER BY statement to your query. SQL Server does not guarantee the order of a result set without ORDER BY

Comment: @RobinHames If the query returns all the values, including the ones which are not in the db, I can do the ordering using c#.

Comment: @Zippy in that case, I would probably apply some filter in C# to the ids List<string> to convert to List<int> with just the relevant values, and pass this to the SQL query. Then construct the required result list in the correct order.

Comment: @Zippy SQL doesn't care about order unless you add an `ORDER BY` clause; either way, that has nothing to do with adding impossible-to-match values like non-integers

Comment: Is it necessary to add the operators (the string values) in SQL or can that be done afterwards in C#?

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden My first option would be SQL but if it can't be done, c# then.

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to receive "value1", "value2", "AND" ??

Comment: @Ben because i need to create the second list as fast as possible.

Comment: But why do you want to create the second list? What is it **for**? What is the **meaning** of the list?

Comment: @Ben I need to display that list to the user.

Comment: Why? What does it mean?

Comment: The user creates the second list, I save it to the db using the 1st list format and when i show the object back to the user it has to be in the 2nd list format in order to use it later.

Comment: Why? What does the list mean? Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Ben Because the list is used in an internal search engine.

Comment: So it isn't a list at all, it's a search expression which has been parsed, search tokens have been replaced with keys and the keys are to be used in the search? Why don't you just store the original expression?

Comment: @Ben Something like that and because the same key can be used in multiple expressions, even twice in the same one. Also, a key can have synonyms which are used in the search. For example, value1 can have as synonyms value1.2 and value1.3. All of these need to be used.

Comment: How many keys are there? A hundred? A million?

Comment: @Ben as of now, closing in to 100k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to extract those list entries which need to be converted, i.e. your search keys, from the list.

Once done, you can query those like so:

```
select id, title from MyTable where id in ( /* list goes here*/)
```

Load the results of the query into a `Dictionary<int,string>`.

Then, go over the list a second time, replacing the keys with the values from your dictionary.

If you find that the SQL query performs badly you should look at indexes and query hints, or ask again for a faster query.

**Why this might improve performance**

The main reason is it will reduce trips to the database. However if the database is on the same physical machine this is unlikely to be significant.

Alternatively, if the list of keys and titles does not change often, and it's OK for it to be slightly out of date, you might load the whole thing into a dictionary. 100,000 entries is not that many - if they are 50 bytes each that's only 5 MB which is not very much on a modern server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast the Id in your SQL-Query

```
SELECT Title
FROM MyTable where cast(Id as nvarchar) in (1,2,'AND')
```

but this would greatly reduce your performance

Comment: If `Id` is an `int`, that is a horrible idea performance wise

Comment: @MarcGravell added your note to the answer

Comment: By using this I don't get the expected result, `AND` is not returned by the query. Be aware that `AND` is not in the table.